# Нужен плагин для стилизации type="number"

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, плагин

Нужен плагин для стилизации поля воода чисел вот такого типа http://prntscr.com/e5tvwz (что бы свести к минимуму редактирование цсс) Сейчас на уме один jqueryFormStyler но там придется добротно так подкрутить стили. Может кто знает плагин с уже дефолтным состоянием того что на скрине.

Comment: Хосподе, это не трудно =_=. Че сразу-то готовый сайт не скачаешь?

Comment: Под такие задачи ставить плагин....

Answer (score 1):

> Вот тебе простой пример(самый минимальный) без использования плагинов
>
> Дальше уже фантазируй и меняй под себя как угодно!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.minus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('.plus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="text" value="1"/>
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: На планшетном компьютере не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот https://1c-dev.ru/number-plugin/ плагин именно для input[type=number], не так как на скрине конечно, но стилями всё равно править придётся под дизайн сайта