# input с боковыми кнопками

Tags: html, jquery

Есть HTML-код с инпутом, в котором числовые значения, там же кнопки увеличения\уменьшения. Как с помощью Jquery сделать эти кнопки по бокам от инпута? 
Заранее спасибо.

```
<input type="number" 
class="input-text qty text" 
step="1" min="1" max="" 
name="quantity_12730" 
value="1" 
title="Кол-во" size="4" 
pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: сделать можно с помощью html и css, jquery тут не при делах, разве что вы хотите динамически переместить элементы в дереве

Comment: Просто кнопки должны быть по бокам и выполнять те же функции, что они выполняют в этом html-коде. Как это сделать без js я не знаю, но весьма интересно.

Comment: а, вы тут про стандартные вверх-вниз в самом поле которые? ну да, без js не сделаете.

Comment: дак а в чем сложность? сделать кнопки по бокам, или менять значения инпута при нажатии на них?

Comment: Да-да, про них. 
Не могу понять как менять значения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужен плагин для стилизации type="number"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624845/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-type-number)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменять стрелки в input \[type="number"\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711651/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-input-type-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var count = $('input').val();

$('#left').click(function(){
   count--;
   $('input').val(count);
});

$('#right').click(function(){
   count++;
   $('input').val(count);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#left, #right {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
<
</div>
<div class="wrapper"><input type="number" 
class="input-text qty text" 
step="1" min="1" max="" 
name="quantity_12730" 
value="1" 
title="Кол-во" size="4" 
pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"></div>
<div id="right">
>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```